# EF database-first approach with 2 databases (test db and production db)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first, database-first

I'm developing a web API with existing database and it has 600k+ records on it. I will be using EF with a database-first approach and planning to clone the production db for staging purposes.

I'm planning to generate 2 `.edmx` models (production and testing) and the I just change the context name in my repository to point to the right context

Is there any best way to do it?

Sorry this is my first time to do database-first approach

Thanks in advance!

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried using different connection strings using Web.config for different configuration environments?

Comment: Yes already tried it but if there's a changes on db I need to update also the models.